# Dimension of vector space of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

I read on vector spaces lately and then I did a thought experiment. As for a vector in R3 the dimension is 3 (maybe you could give me a proof?), i asked myself what would the dimension be of a vector space of polynomials with degree <= k? I currently think it is infinite as you can always add another polynomial that is not expressible as a linear sum of the set, but I do not have any solid proof for this statement.

Comment: It is $k+1$, One basis is $1,x,x^2,\dots,x^k$.

Comment: But i can write a different set of k+1 polynomials that are also linearly independent right? Or can one proof that it impossible

Comment: There are, as usual, plenty of linearly independent sets of size $k+1$, just as there are infinitely many bases for the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$.  As a simple example we could use $1,x+17,x^2,x^3,\dots,x^k$.  But (general theorem) all bases have the same size. Proving that every polynomial of degree $\le k$ is a linear combination of the polynomials mentioned in the first comment is easy. It takes some work, not too bad, to show they are linearly independent.

Comment: Right but is a independent set of k + 2 also possible? That would suggest a higher dimension

Comment: Sort of answered above, it is a general theorem that if there is a basis of size $n$, then any set of $n+1$ or more vectors is linearly dependent.

Comment: "you can always add another polynomial that is not expressible as a linear sum of the set": are you sure ? What makes you say that ?

Answer (score 5):

Any quadratic polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ is obviously a linear combination of the three polynomials $x^2$, $x$ and $1$, so that the space of polynomials of degree $\le2$ is *at most* of dimension $3$.

You can generalize to any degree.

Comment: I didn't understand why at most 3.It should be exactly 3 no.

Comment: @Believer: the one implies the other.

Answer (score 2):

The set $\{1, x, x^{2}...,x^{k}\}$ form a basis of the vector space of all polynomials of degree $\leq k$ over some field. Every polynomial will be in some linear combination of these vectors. Also it is not difficult to show that the above set is linear independent. So dimension of the vector space is $k+1$. Your vector space has infinite polynomials but every polynomial has degree $\leq k$ and so is in the linear span of the set $\{1, x, x^{2}...,x^{k}\}$.

$$OR$$

Basis is maximal linear independent set or minimal generating set. Since every polynomial is of degree $\leq k,$ set $\{1, x, x^{2}...,x^{k}\}$ is a minimal generating set or a basis. Now one can say by definition of basis that any $k+2$ vectors form a linear dependent set.

Comment: But can you prove me it is not possible to write a set of k + 2 or higher being linear independent?

Comment: But that does not mean that every possible k + 2 set or higher is linearly dependent right

Comment: Basis is maximal l.i. set and minimal generating set....any polynomial is in linear combination of vectors of above set...so it minimal generating set...and hence basis. So any k+2 vectors do not form a basis.

Comment: But the definition of dimension was that for a given set of n equal to the dimension, ANY set of n + 1 is linearly dependent

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the definition of a basis of a vector space is a set of vectors such that they are linearly independent, i.e if any linear combination of the basis vectors is zero then the coefficients of each basis vector must be zero and that they span the vector space i.e any vector can be written as a linear combination of the basis. So a basis for $R^3$ is simply the set {(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)}. Of course there are infinitely many possible bases for a vector space, {(2,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)} is another basis for $R^3$. Similarly {$1,x,x^2,x^3,...,x^{k}$} is a basis for the set of polynomials of degree k. You can easily see that this set satisfies the above 2 properties to be a basis.

I would have commented above but I don't have enough reputation. To answer your question about why the dimension of the vector space has to be unique, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces